# Kill all queries and single use rmode Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are building a deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps and we think that we need to kill queries running on the objects that may be changed by the deployment of the code. Is that true? And how can we prevent Snowflake from starting queries again?

Thanks
Hennie